# How can I make AngularJS simply print the date without applying a time zone ?

Tags: angularjs, date, filter

I return from WEBapi a date like

2013-01-01T00:00:00

And I want

```
  {{msa.StartDate | date:'yyyy-MM'}}
```

To be

2013-01

But because it wants to take my current time zone in consideration (US eastern) it is

2012-12

Is there a easy way to tell it DO NOT CARE ABOUT TIMEZONES? Or is there some other filter I can run the date through to ignore my time zone?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way it's *printing* the date. The problem is that it's *deserializing* the date as UTC (just like it should for ISO8601 if it doesn't know better), and it's not.

Comment: But the value coming from the server to the client is 2013-01-01T00:00:00 and I just want it to use that date and not imply a change do to a time zone or whatever.. seems like a simple thing to want..

Comment: You could create your own filter using momentjs (momentjs.com). This appears to give you what you want: moment('2013-01-01T00:00:00').format('YYYY-MM');

Comment: this will work with angularJS filters? Do you have an example  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is described in documentation "If no timezone is specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the local timezone." (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date). So you can set time zone yourself. For example this will use UTC time zone

`{{'2013-01-01T00:00:00' + 'Z' | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}`

Result (I'm on the West Coast and have 8 hours difference with London)

`2012-12-31 16:00`

Comment: Where did you actually specify the time zone in your example ? As I read the docs Z is just for showing the time zone.. I didn't see anything for changing the default timezone.. In my case I guess I would want the +-0 timezone wherever that may be so it will not change the time in my date

Comment: oh.. I got it.. its  {{msa.StartDate + '-05:00' | date:'yyyy-MM'}}

Comment: well that only works in IE and not chrome it seems. SIGH

Comment: Works for me in Chrome and Safari. {{'2013-01-01T00:00:00' + '-08:00' | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}} results to 2013-01-01 00:00 (West Coast)

Answer (score 2):

As of at least Angular 1.4 you can use the date filter's "timezone" parameter to format the date for a given offset. In this case, to keep the time unchanged, use "UTC".

```
{{msa.StartDate | date:'yyyy-MM':'UTC'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, spent lot of time to fix. Finally I am able to solve. Instead of sending as datetime type, I sent to backend as a string. Since its Rest API endpoint, automatically converted to Date Time.

```
model.dateOfBirth = new Date(moment(model.dateOfBirth).format('MM/DD/YYYY')).toDateString();
```

This solved my problem.