# Angular $http date issue

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I have an angularJs single-page app that posts data to an ASP.NET WebApi server application. Data is passed to the angular $http service as a javascript object:

```
saveData: function (data) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api/Case/SaveData',
        data: data
    }).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.reject(data.Message || data);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

The data object contains several precise javascript dates (ie. they have a zero time component). When these dates are parsed by the WebApi model binder, their value is resolved taking into account the Daylight Saving state for the date in question. So "01/06/1965" resolves as "31/05/1965 23:00".

I suspect this is because when angular transforms the javascript object into JSON, it renders dates using the date.toString() method rather than date.toUTCString().

How can I configure the $http service so that it passes the dates to the server as UTC dates rather than with a local date?

Comment: have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379869/date-in-angularjs-are-sent-in-utc-in-resource-save/21388870#21388870

Comment: Thanks, playing around with that, I discovered that the dates are in fact strings. Investigating further.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make AngularJS simply print the date without applying a time zone ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846567/how-can-i-make-angularjs-simply-print-the-date-without-applying-a-time-zone)